# Poison ivy products Zanfel and Tecnu — Ontario availability?

Tags: poison-ivy

I stumbled onto a Reddit post that has some tips for dealing with poison ivy rashes: [Poison ivy between my fingers. I'm considering amputation at this point.](https://www.reddit.com/r/mildlyinfuriating/comments/12o6qk7/poison_ivy_between_my_fingers_im_considering/)

In that post, lots of people seem to swear by a product called ***Zanfel***. And also a different product called ***Tecnu*** (to a lesser degree).

Those products sound promising. I tried searching **google.ca** ([Canada filter](https://www.google.ca/search?cr=countryCA&tbs=ctr:countryCA&q=Zanfel&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9__3g-sr_AhVSjYkEHTChAb4QBSgAegQIEBAB&biw=1920&bih=969&dpr=1)) to see if any Canadian stores carry those products. But I didn't find much.

Where can I find products like Zanfel, Tecnu, or an equivalent product, in brick-and-mortar stores in Ontario?

Comment: Active ingredients is more likely - anionic detergent (lauroyl sarcosinate or octylphenoxy-polythoxethanol +/- mineral spirits in these cases), surfactant (nonoxyenol-9, soap) and something to physically remove the urushiol (polyethylene granules) seem to be the components, but what mix you would need is another question.